# Invoke IE search functionality from ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to programmatically invoke default search functionality of IE using ASP.net , for example when an page load a specific term should be searched  and highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. But you can use javascript to search and highlight specific term in the page.

visit this page ( [Javascript](http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm) ) and look the page source. you can re-use their script or get an idea.

also you can try jquery plugin.
[Jquery Plugin](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2008/11/17/search-on-this-page-using-jquery/)

Comment: Can you please explain me how?